# Python Newbie – How do I make VS Code running Python 3 only display the result of the code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I run python code in the PyCharm IDE it simply and cleanly shows the output. But when I run python code in the Microsoft VS Code editor it shows the following:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
PS C:\Users\MY ACTUAL NAME\Desktop\Pythonista> python -u "c:\Users\MY ACTUAL NAME \Desktop\Pythonista\Exercise_3.py"
"RESULT OF CODE HERE"
PS C:\Users\MY ACTUAL NAME\Desktop\Pythonista>
```

The code executes underneath the Terminal label; to the left of the Problems, Output, and Debug Console headers. Why can’t it just show the result of my code without all the other details. The reason I ask is because I am trying to record myself doing the work, but I do not want my name broadcasted and I just want the output to look cleaner. Is this a thing? Thanks.

Edit: put code in a code block.

Comment: change the prompt of the terminal and call the python exe your self. If PyCharm does what you want use PyCharm

Comment: `cmd` is slightly less filled with random text. You could change it in your `settings.json`

Comment: while using clear does eliminate some things, I still have that address showing. How do I use settings.json. It looks like I'll screw something up in there.

Comment: 1. `Control` + `Shift` + `P`

2. type in "open settings (json)"

3. Open up the file

4. Add this line: `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `try` and `except` so the errors won't appear in the terminal

example:

```
try:
    # put your code here
except Exception:
    pass
```

Comment: Im not getting errors, i was talking about the extra text that shows with my code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Press `Crtl + J` to open a terminal (or Powershell in your case), then run your code with the command `python3 file.py`.

Do this as opposed to clicking "Run" in the IDE, which is what most people do.

*Note: when you open the terminal up initially, if it is full of jargon you don't want displaying, type `clear` (or the equivalent on Windows, which I think is `cls`).*

Comment: this has cleared up a lot of extra text when running my code. Now there only one line that reads PS C:\Users\MY ACTUAL NAME\Desktop\Pythonista>

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see that is what you meant to get rid of. In that case, it has nothing to do with clearing your terminal. You can look into shortening your command line path, something I can't help you with here.

Comment: If running your code in PyCharm doesn't cause you this problem, and you don't know how to or want to change your command line path, I would say stick with PyCharm.

Comment: The reason is because PyCharm seem to be heavy on my PC, old Lenovo Yoga laptop, VS Code, recommended by a classmate runs smoother

Answer (score 0):

The right question that I needed to ask was, how do I shorten my path in VS Code and how do I get rid of the extra text that appears just before my code in the terminal after execution. After doing some research, it appears these questions have been asked many times. Below is how it is done for any other newbie like myself that stumbles upon this.

First, go to VS Code, File, Preferences, Settings, click button on the top right corner to open settings.json. Paste this,

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-NoLogo"],
```

Next, while it is impossible to hide your path in VS code from the code output, you can certainly make your output look cleaner by moving the folder location from where the piece of code is stored. All together, when I executed my code, this is what it looked like before:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\MY NAME\Desktop\Pythonista> python -u "c:\Users\MY NAME\Desktop\Pythonista\Exercise_3.py"
Hello StackOverflow
```

And now, after moving my code file location closer to C:, and editing settings.json, when I execute my code, it looks like this,

```
PS C:\Pythonista> python -u "c:\Pythonista\Exercise_3.py"
Hello StackOverflow
```

Much cleaner, I hope this helps anyone else.